# Изменить GET значение параметра у ссылки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно ввести в поле слово и оно будет автоматом подставляться к GET параметру в ссылке. Вот код. По идее должен менять параметр site на тот, что вводим в текстовое поле.

```
<input id="go" size="38" type="text" value=""">
<a id="change" href="index.php?id=1000&site=" class="golink">Test</a>

<script>
$('#go').change( function() {
return $('#change').replace( /(site=)[^&]+/ig, '$1'+o.target.value );
});
</script>
```

jQuery не знаю вообще, набросал что мог. Помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#go').change( function() {
    var link = $('#change');
    var href = link.attr('href');
    var value = href.replace(/(site=)[^&]+/ig, '$1' + $(this).val());
    link.attr('href', value);
});
```

Comment: не хочет работать

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tdwgf0ym/

Comment: @dimka3210, вроде правильно, но не работает

Comment: @Rammsteinik, потому что 
1. jQuery подключи
2. Пытается заменить пустую строку "" на значение. И валится

http://jsfiddle.net/g9var14L/

Comment: @Rammsteinik так заработало или нет?